# the new notification cancel the old one

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

in my application the user has to add multiple notifications , but my problem is when the user add the new notification the old one deleted or canceled .And I think it's from the pendingIntent , what the appropriate flag should i use ?

here is some of my code :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent intent;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    long futureInMillis;
    switch (type) {
        case SCHEDULE_BY_DAYS:
            intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra(NotificationReceiver.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
            intent.putExtra(NotificationReceiver.NOTIFICATION, getNotification("WAKEP UP days !!"));
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            break;
        case SCHEDULE_BY_HOURS:

            futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + (value * 600000);
            intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra(NotificationReceiver.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
            intent.putExtra(NotificationReceiver.NOTIFICATION, getNotification("WAKEP UP hours"));
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
            break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify a different requestCode for each `PendingIntent` notifications won't cancel each other.

`PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,` *unique_code*`, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`

**Edit**

```
int uniqueCode = sharedPreferences.getInt("unique_code",0) + 1;
sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("unique_code",uniqueCode).apply()
```

Comment: i did not understand , what the unique code will contain ?

Comment: just count upward. First notification gets 1, second gets 2, etc. It just has to be unique and this is the easiest way to ensure just that.

Comment: can u plz give me a sample code to much understand how this will work ?coz it also must cancel the same id .

Comment: I've provided code on how this could work. However you stated in your question that you **don't** want these notifications to be canceled, why do you ask for it now?

Comment: ok  , in my code I specify all requests with 0 , maybe because of that it replaced .

Comment: yes but you say your answer not what im looking for ?

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I reworded it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add the dependency as shown below in your app build.gradle file:

Java: implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1"

Kotlin: implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1"

Then do something like this in your fragment. You don't need requireActivity() if you are inside an activity.

```
`
 val sharedPreferences = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("Notification_data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val customRequestCode = sharedPreferences.getInt("customRequestCode", 0) + 1
    sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("customRequestCode", customRequestCode).apply()
`
```